# Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x837cb90> was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I am trying to Jump from One Uitextfield to another in UItableview on clicking Next button, it is throwing me error message of Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x837cb90> was mutated while being enumerated.whereas Previous button is working perfectly.

This thing happens when I am Second last cell of a tableview and want to move last cell.
Below is some code snippet:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    CustomCell *Cell = ( CustomCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (Cell == nil)
    {

        // a new cell needs to be created
        Cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                         reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
        Cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    NSDictionary* product = [dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    Cell.lblProductContName.text=[product objectForKey:@"ProductContentsandName"];
    Cell.txtQty.delegate = self;
    Cell.txtQty.tag = 100 + row;
    Cell.txtQty.text=[txtFieldArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return Cell;
```

}

Code On Next Button, Previous and Done button.

```
- (void)onPrev:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *visiableCells = [self.myTableView visibleCells];
    [visiableCells enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)obj;

        if (cell.txtQty.tag == selectedCellIndex) {
            [cell.txtQty resignFirstResponder];
        } else if (cell.txtQty.tag == selectedCellIndex - 1){
            [cell.txtQty becomeFirstResponder];
            *stop = YES;
        }

    }];

}

- (void)onNext:(id)sender
{

    NSArray *visiableCells = [self.myTableView visibleCells];


    [visiableCells enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)obj;
            if (cell.txtQty.tag == selectedCellIndex) {
                [cell.txtQty resignFirstResponder];
            } else if (cell.txtQty.tag == selectedCellIndex + 1){
                [cell.txtQty becomeFirstResponder];
                *stop = YES;
            }

        }];

}

- (void)onDone:(id)sender
{
    NSArray *visiableCells = [self.myTableView visibleCells];

    [visiableCells enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)obj;
        if (cell.txtQty.tag == selectedCellIndex) {
            [cell.txtQty resignFirstResponder];
        }


    }];

}
```

Comment: Code formatting? If you fix it, people will be more inclined to read your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A long shot but, probably because of the keyboard being hidden/shown or another UI constrain which I imagine depends on the number of cells (trying with 100 cells will probably make it crash at the last cell that fits the screen without scrolling) and table view size, the number of visible cells get's mutated when you call resign/become first responder (aka, the table view shows different cells). Try to make a copy of the array first:

`NSArray *visibleCells = [[self.myTableView visibleCells] copy];`

Comment: Tons of thanks @Valentin.. After changing the code. it works..Thanks once again

Answer (score 4):

By sending a becomeFirstResponder message to a text field inside a table view you can cause it to scroll. By scrolling the visibleCells array gets changed. And since this happens while you are enumerating this array you get the exception.

But you don't need to iterate over the visible cells. Just use the UITableView method cellForRowAtIndexPath: to get the next or previous cell. Also you don't have to call resignFirstResponder yourself. When a new view becomes the first responder the old one automatically resigns.